# Oracle listagg regexp_substr for code extraction and concatination

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-substr

I am working with PL/SQL v10 on Oracle 11g database.
I have codes that are being stored in description column of question table that I need to extract.
To do that I was working on producing regex [which works fine in 101regex](http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/13) but fails in oracle,
I would assume I was using incorrect syntax.

```
select '''' || listagg(regexp_substr(q.questiondescription,'(LIF|LPA) ?\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}(\.\d{1})?'), ''', ''') 
within group (order by q.questionid) || '''' 
from question q
where q.isthunderheadonly = 0 or q.isthunderheadonly is null
```

Patterns that I need to match:

```
LIF 1.2 Both
LIF 2.7.1 Address Line 1
LIF 4.13 Occupation
LIF 10.6.1 Address Line 1
LPA0.1 What type of LPA do you want?
LPA0.2 Do you have same attorneys with your partner ?
```

**Where did I go wrong with my regex?**

**EDIT:** result I am getting

```
'LIF 3.1', 'LIF 4.1', 'LIF 4.2', 'LIF 5.1', 'LIF 7.1', 'LPA0.1', 'LPA0.2'
```

it's ignoring everything after second group I think.

Comment: What are you matching and what are you not matching? You've got a space after `(LIF|LPA)`, which doesn't exist in `LPA0.1 What type of LPA do you want?`.

Comment: [They were wrong](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_posix003.htm#SQLRF55544) @Avinash.

Comment: @vks didn't fly, sorry

Comment: @AvinashRaj didn't do it

Comment: if you want to capture all then surround the pattern within a capturing group http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/15 use `\s*` instead of ` ?`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `((LIF|LPA) \s*\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}(\.\d{1})?)` didn't do it

Comment: `(LIF|LPA)\s*\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}(\.\d{1})?`

Comment: @AvinashRaj same result, sorry.

Comment: @LIUFA could you post your code in sqlfiddle?

Comment: @AvinashRaj solved by Maheswaran Ravisankar, it had something to do with oracle not accepting `\d` but it worked with `(LIF |LPA)[([:digit:]|.)]*` it is really weird.

Comment: @LIUFA i already told it to you.. but Ben said like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378369/oracle-listagg-regexp-substr-for-code-extraction-and-concatination?noredirect=1#comment41411993_26378369)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(LIF |LPA)\d{1,2}(.\d{1,2})*(\.\d{1})?
```

OR

```
(LIF |LPA)[([:digit:]|.)]*
```

This would match.

Demo:

```
SQL> l
  1  with my_data(str,num) as
  2  (
  3  select 'LIF 1.1.1 First Name',1 from dual
  4  union all
  5  select 'LIF 1.2 Date Of Birth' ,1 from dual
  6  union all
  7  select 'LIF 1.2 Date Of Birth' ,2 from dual
  8  union all
  9  select 'LIF 7.10 How many other properties do you own?',1 from dual
 10  union all
 11  select 'DT 05. Do you have children?',1 from dual
 12  union all
 13  select 'LIF 15 Notes to solicitor',1  from dual
 14  union all
 15  SELECT 'LPA0.2 Do you have same attorneys with your partner' ,1 from dual
 16  )
 17  select str, regexp_substr(str,'(LIF |LPA)\d{1,2}(.\d{1,2})*(\.\d{1})*') regex1,
 18  regexp_substr(str,'(LIF |LPA)[([:digit:]|.)]*') regex2
 19  from my_data
 20* group by str
SQL> /

STR                                                          REGEX1               REGEX2
------------------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
LPA0.2 Do you have same attorneys with your partner          LPA0.2               LPA0.2
DT 05. Do you have children?
LIF 1.1.1 First Name                                         LIF 1.1.1            LIF 1.1.1
LIF 1.2 Date Of Birth                                        LIF 1.2              LIF 1.2
LIF 15 Notes to solicitor                                    LIF 15               LIF 15
LIF 7.10 How many other properties do you own?               LIF 7.10             LIF 7.10

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: It produces same result as others `'LIF 3.1', 'LIF 4.1', 'LIF 4.2', 'LIF 5.1', 'LIF 7.1', 'LPA0.1', 'LPA0.2'` altho I must admit placing space into `(LIF |LPA)` is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

I change the Regex so hope it can work fine on your oracle :)

```
L(IF|PA\d{1,}(\.\d{1,}){0,1}) {1,}(\d{1,}(\.\d{1,}){0,}){0,1}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UqYfZV1TOWQnpekm)

Comment: No sorry, I need to capture `LIF 1.2` , `LIF 2.7.1` , ... `LPA0.2`

Comment: after edit it produces `'LIF 3.1', 'LIF 4.1', 'LIF 4.2', 'LIF 5.1', 'LIF 7.1', 'LPA0.1 ', 'LPA0.2 '` so it skips `LIF 2.7.1` and `LIF 10.6.1`

Comment: @LIUFA yes, so I update it again, see if what you want

Comment: same result it's missing `LIF 2.7.1` and `LIF 10.6.1`

Comment: It does match but so does my initial example in question, this would imply that regex syntax for oracle is different from python. Thanks for helping me BTW.

Comment: @LIUFA I change the Regex so hope it can work fine on your oracle :)

    `L(IF|PA\d{1,}(\.\d{1,}){0,1})\s(\d{1,}(\.\d{1,}){0,}){0,1}`

Comment: Didn't fly. It also added spaces at the end of LPA `'LIF 3.1', 'LIF 4.1', 'LIF 4.2', 'LIF 5.1', 'LIF 7.1', 'LPA0.1 ', 'LPA0.2 '`